# @Html.DisplayFor -- лишние пустые строки и пробельные символы

Tags: html, bootstrap, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Есть во вьюшке такой кусок кода:

```
<td style="word-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre-line">
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Checks[i].Value)
</td>
```

Отрисовывается это дело так:
[image: 1]

**Вопрос:** как убрать пустую строку перед текстом? Весь измучался уже.

P.S. С `white-space:pre-wrap` появляются еще пробельные символы и выглядит это так:
[image: 2]

Comment: `white-space:normal;` ?

Comment: У меня текст многострочный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишите так:

```
<td style="word-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre-line">@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Checks[i].Value)</td>
```

Если вы прописали `white-space:pre-line`, вы должны учитывать, что вот этот символ будет отображаться:

```
<td style="word-wrap:break-word; white-space:pre-line">=>
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.Checks[i].Value)
</td>
```

Где `=>` - переход на новую строку.